# Nested ActionSheetPicker, picker within done block of another

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I have just got a barrier that I can't nest ActionSheetPickers. I'm using an iOS library [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) developed by Tim Cinel which is really effective. However, I met a problem when I want to nest multiple pickers. What I want to do is showing three action sheet pickers one by one (after user tapped done button, another should show). The first picker will be shown without problems, but the second one will appear and immediately disappear.
Here is my code

```
[ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Choose Date" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:[NSDate date] doneBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker, NSDate *selectedDate, id origin) {
            // update choosed date
            [self updateInspectionDate:selectedDate atIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            // start another action sheet for start time
            [ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Start Time" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime selectedDate:[NSDate date] doneBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker, NSDate *selectedDate, id origin) {
                // update start time
                [self updateInspectionStartTime:selectedDate atIndexPath:indexPath];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                // start another action sheet for end time
                [ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"End Time" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime selectedDate:[NSDate date] doneBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker, NSDate *selectedDate, id origin) {
                    // update choosed time
                    [self updateInspectionEndTime:selectedDate atIndexPath:indexPath];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                } cancelBlock:nil origin:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
            } cancelBlock:nil origin:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        } cancelBlock:nil origin:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I had response from the original author of this library.

Here is his explanation:

> So, done block calls right after button pressed and picker not hidden
>   yet. That's why new picker is not rise up. Since it's not the first
>   time, that someone ask about this case - I'll try to resolve this
>   issue soon.
>
> Now, as workaround - you can wait for 0.3 seconds before rise up new
>   picker.

After that I tried the solution he advised

```
[self performSelector:@selector(second:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.4];
```

Everything then works like a charm :-)

Comment: Trying to do the same thing but I'm calling the picker from 10 different locations with just 1 helper implementation file, so there is no [self that refers to a view so I'll have to pass that info in and see if that works.

Comment: @StuartP.  I think the author has already  solved this problem since there are many users claimed this issue, which means, we even don't need to perform after a delay now. How about check out the most recent version of this library and try again?

Comment: I pulled the latest via Cocoapods, I couldn't do the selector anyways due to this being in a little library I'm building, just performing on the main queue seemed to bypass the issue on both iOS7 & 8 but thanks for the reply, maybe the pod spec isn't on the latest build.